# how to add content limit on custom admin grid

Tags: magento2.3, admin, grid, custom-admin-grid

I want to add content limit to 50 characters on content of the admin grid for specific column.
Can anyone help me out.

[image]

below is the code used for this grid :
/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/gridanswer_record_grid_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">gridanswer_record_grid_list.gridanswer_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">gridanswer_record_grid_list.gridanswer_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">grid_records_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Question</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/addrow</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="gridanswer_record_grid_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">gridanswer_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>

        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
    </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">gridanswer_record_grid_list.gridanswer_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <!-- Mass actions which you want to add in your grid-->
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="gridanswer/grid/massdelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Do you want to delete selected row record?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">gridanswer_record_grid_list.gridanswer_record_grid_list.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">gridanswer_record_grid_list.gridanswer_record_grid_list.grid_records_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>                          
                    </item> 
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
    </container>
    <columns name="grid_records_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                   <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">0</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </selectionsColumn>
       <column name="entity_id">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <!-- <column name="vendor_id">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Vendor ID</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column> -->
       <column name="name">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="email" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="question" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message By Seller</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="answer" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message By Admin</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="is_answered" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Status</item>
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">4</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="update_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Time</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" >
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                   <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </column>
       <!-- Add Action with each row of grid and for this we will create a class Action -->
       <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\Action">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                   <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: Can you please add some code for how you are rendering the grid? Using block file or ui component?

Comment: @RahulBarot This is rendered using ui component.
I have also added the code in description of question.

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use renderer for each column to modify the content of it. For example for `question` column

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/gridanswer_record_grid_list.xml

```
<column name="question" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Question">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Message By Seller</item>
           <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
       </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

> Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Question.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

class Question extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $item['question'] = substr($item['question'],0,50);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks It worked.

Comment: You're welcome :)